# Move Virtual PC VM to Hyper-V VM

Tags: virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc, hyper-v

Is there a way to take a Virtual PC VM and convert it so that it can be opened with MS Hyper-V?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to create a new VM in Hyper-V (make sure to match the memory of your Virtual PC VM) and attach the `.vhd` to the IDE controller.

While looking for an article regarding this procedure (which I just can't find), at least I found this article named [Migrating a virtual machine from Virtual PC to Hyper-V and back](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2009/08/29/migrating-a-virtual-machine-from-virtual-pc-to-hyper-v-and-back.aspx), which I hope will serve you just as well.

Comment: The original article can be found on the Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20090923111315/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2009/08/29/migrating-a-virtual-machine-from-virtual-pc-to-hyper-v-and-back.aspx